# How can I use slides with ionic and pagination only certain pages?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pagination, swiper.js

I'm using ionic slides:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/

I want to use pagination with bullet:

[image]

That work fine, but now I have:

- A title slide
- Than 5-6 slides for this title
- Than another title slide
- Than 5-6 slides for this title
- ETC

I want than have the bullets only for the title pages.

Anybody know how can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: So you want to have a title screen with 5-6 bullets on it and when you reach the next title screen there are 5-6 new bullets for the next pages. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: no, the first page contain all the bullets. But only the bullets for the title pages. The others pages has no bullets

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean. Can you describe the problem again, please?

Comment: An example: I have 15 slides: 1.- Global title slide, 2.- Title slide, 3.- slide related with 2, 4.- slide related with 2, 5.- slide related with 2, 6.- Title slide, 3.- slide related with 6, 7.- slide related with 6, 8.- slide related with 6, 9.- slide related with 6, 10.- Title slide, 11.- slide related with 10, 12.- slide related with 10, 13.- slide related with 10, 14.- slide related with 10, 15.- slide related with 10. Then in the Global Title page, I want to have bullets of pagination, but not 15 bullets, only bullets for titles pages (2, 6, 10)

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Could you give me feedback if it's working for you or if it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I will test it now and say to you, but as I see it seem to be good, thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help, that is exactly what I needed! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do. Basically I would **define the title pages** like this:

```js
private titleSlides = {
    "1": "title",
    "5": "title",
    "8": "title"
};
```

Then I wrote this function to **hide bullets** that aren't title pages:

```js
@ViewChild(Slides) private slides: Slides;

private changePagination () : void {
    // get active index
    let index = this.slides.getActiveIndex();
    // get the pager bullets (maybe need to be selected different, when multiple slides on one page)
    let bullets = document.getElementsByClassName('swiper-pagination-bullet');

    for (let i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
        if (index == 0) {
            if (this.titleSlides[i]) {
                (bullets[i] as HTMLElement).style.display = 'inline-block';
            } else {
                (bullets[i] as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';
            }
        } else {
            (bullets[i] as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

To call this function you can use following **lifecycle/onChange functions**:

```js
ionSlideDidChange() {
    this.changePagination();
}

ngAfterViewChecked () {
    this.changePagination();
}
```

And finally your **html**:

```html
<ion-slides pager="true" (ionSlideDidChange)="ionSlideDidChange()">
    <ion-slide>
        Global
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        Title
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        Slide 1
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        Slide 2
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        Slide 3
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        Title
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        Slide 1
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        Slide 2
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        Title
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        Slide 1
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```